# get descendants in hierarchyid sql server

Tags: sql-server, hierarchy

I am attaching image of my problem below:-

[image]

If you can see I am running the query correctly to get the child of the specific node.

But i am getting the node itself together with it which i don't want.

Can you please suggest something?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and cms.ManagementHierarchy.ToString() <> @CurrentNode ?